# Apply styles to a class if it matches an element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way of achieving this. I have two classes of .error, however if the class is on a P tag element I want to add a few additional styles.

Reason being the HTML is generated automatically, so applying additional classes can not be done.

Comment: Re-read the section on selectors in good documentation such as MDN. From their "Selectors" page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors: "You can also combine selectors, making a more specific selector. For example, the selector `.key` selects all elements that have the class name `key`. The selector `p.key` selects only `<p>` elements that have the class name `key`."

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) as well as a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) in your stylesheet.

```
p.error { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a more specific rule for p tags:

```
.error {

}

p.error {

}
```